# Can I go back home to Mexico through Belgium if I only have the right of residence in Poland?

Tags: visas, airports, belgium, mexican-citizens

My Visa in Poland had expired and I applied for a new one so it means I'm allowed to stay in Poland but NOT to travel outside. I need to go back home to Mexico but there's no direct flight and I would have a layover in Belgium. Can I travel back home through country im not allowed to be in?

Comment: What happened to your residence permit?

Comment: It might be easier to fly via the UK or an other 'non-Schengen' country.

Comment: I had temporary residence permit and it expired and I applied again but it takes a year for them to issue a decision.

Comment: What is the difference between "non-Schengen" and "Schengen" country in this situation?

Comment: Since you are not allowed to leave the country, what will happen if you do so anyway?

Comment: @Ala If you fly directly from Poland to a non Schengen country (assuming you have necessary documents to transit in that country), the exit check will be done by Polish authorities who presumably can verify your status more easily. However, you should check with the foreigner's office if a short term Schengen visa can be issued allowing to exit and re-enter Schengen area.

Comment: Further to @KristvanBesien's comment: the prohibition on leaving while an application is pending usually means (in countries I'm familiar with, which do not include Poland) that the application is considered abandoned, and you may not return unless you get a visa while you are abroad.  You should definitely consider the consequences of leaving Poland before you do it.